MySql jdbc socket closes 5% of streaming queries
The code connects to read-replica db using com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource. For each of about 800 long-running medium to large queries (10k - 200k rows) running in parallel (64 coroutine limit), in order to prevent OOM, it uses a new connection with no queryTimeout on a separate thread than the body of code processing each result (which may itself execute a different Hikari managed db query to a different db connect against the primary db). In about 25-30 calls, in the midst of rapidly processing rows (no obvious time gap in log for the thread), it will get
java.io.IOException: Socket is closed.
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.AbstractSocketConnection.getMysqlInput(Abstract

I've tried ensuring all nested db access is indeed on a different thread so they cannot share transaction.
The streaming code
      database.transactionManager.newConnection().use { connection ->
        connection.isReadOnly = true
        database.dirtyExecuteExpression(expression) { statement ->
            logger.debug { "Running query: $statement" }
            if (database.dialect is MySqlDialect) statement.fetchSize = Integer.MIN_VALUE
            statement.queryTimeout = 0 // no timeout
            try {
                statement.executeQuery().use { rs ->
                    logger.debug { "Query: $rs" }
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        action(rs)
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: SQLException) {
                logger.error(e) { "Error during suspendable query $statement on ${statement.connection}" }
                throw e
            }
        }
    }

/**
 * Sets `transactionIsolation` to [Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED] which means no locking, but is
 * otherwise a copy of [Database.executeExpression]
 */
inline fun <T> Database.dirtyExecuteExpression(expression: SqlExpression, func: (PreparedStatement) -> T): T {
    val (sql, args) = formatExpression(expression)

    // the pattern is to use a non-pooled DB if the body is likely to do db queries.
    useConnection { conn ->
        conn.transactionIsolation = Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED
        // see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html
        conn.prepareStatement(sql, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY).use { statement ->
            statement.setArguments(args)
            return func(statement)
        }
    }
}

I can't seem to catch the exception in the stack frame which would know how to idempotently restart or even resume using a cursor.
Any ideas on possible cause and either retry or guard clause to check? also, is there anyway to ensure socketTimeout is 0
